# How to Return Tag name using attribute value inside the tag of xml using java

Tags: java, xml

I need to return the **TAG Name** using Java code. I have a **tag name Interaction** in my XML file and it had a attribute name called id. I use to give or Hard code an id value in a program. **Example: String id="244_choice_list_12";** I need to return Tag name. **Tag Name: Interaction**. Without using Xpath

```
package com.video.convertor;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.util.ArrayList;

 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

 import org.w3c.dom.Document;
 import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
 import org.w3c.dom.Node;
 import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class ReadChildId {

public static void main(String[] args) 
throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    File xmlFile = new File("/Users/myXml/Sample.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory   dbFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    walkNode(doc);
}

private static void walkNode(Node node) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        checkChildNode(nodeList.item(i));
    }
}

private static void checkChildNode(Node node) {
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        checkAttributes(node);

        walkNode(node);
    }
}
private static void checkAttributes(Node node) {
    if (node.hasAttributes()) {
        NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();

        printAttributes(attributes);
    }
}

private static void printAttributes(NamedNodeMap attributes) {

    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
       Node attribute = attributes.item(i);
       if (attribute.getNodeName() == "id") {
       //System.out.println("Attribute found: " +  attribute.getNodeName()+ " : " + attribute.getNodeValue());
       String x = attribute.getNodeValue();
       String attr="244_choice_list_12";
       if(attr.equals(x)){
           //Node tag = attribute.getNodeName();
            System.out.println("Tag found :"+ "\t"+ x.);

        }else{
            System.out.println("There No such as Tag");
        }
      /*for(int j = 0;j < x.length();j++){ 
       if(attr.equals(x)){
           Node tag = attribute.getParentNode();
            System.out.println("Tag found :"+ "\t"+ tag);

        }else{
            System.out.println("There No such as Tag");
        }
      }*/
        //String 
       // String Value1 = attribute.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
        //System.out.println("Attribute found: " +attribute.getNamedItem("id") + " : "+ attribute.getNodeName() + " : " + attribute.getNodeValue()));
        //System.out.println("Attribute:" +Value1 );
        }
        }

}}
```

```html
xml File:
<itemBody class="etsmcm01fmt" id="244_item_content_3">
<rubric class="item_response_information " id="244_item_response_information_21" use="instruction" view="author proctor scorer testConstructor tutor"/>
<xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="../Passage/205.qti.xml"/>
<div class="stimulus_reference " id="244_stimulus_reference_4">
    <p class="introduction passage-intro " id="244_introduction_5">Read<span class="formatted_text text_decoration:underline " id="200244_formatted_text_6">two</span> sentences</p>
</div>
<Interaction class="choice_list " id="244_choice_list_12" maxChoices="4" minChoices="0" responseIdentifier="RESPONSE" shuffle="false">
    <prompt id="244_item_stem_8">
        <p class="stem_paragraph " id="244_stem_paragraph_9">story</p>
    </prompt>
    <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_13" identifier="i1">
        <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_14">North and south</p>
    </simpleChoice>
    <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_15" identifier="i2">
        <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_16">Sun and Moon</p>
    </simpleChoice>
    <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_17" identifier="i3">
        <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_18">uncomfortable.</p>
    </simpleChoice>
    <simpleChoice class="block_choice " id="200244_block_choice_19" identifier="i4">
        <p class="choice_paragraph " id="200244_choice_paragraph_20">head.</p>
    </simpleChoice>
</Interaction></itemBody>
```

Comment: `attribute.getNodeName() == "id"` .... so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to access the document.

```
function loadXMLDocument(url){
     var xmlHttpRequest = new xmlHttpRequest();
     xmlHttpRequest.open("get", url, false);
     xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
     var doc = xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
     findTagMatchingId(doc);
}
```

Use this to get the nodes. Html Vs XML DOM is different. The commands are practically the same except for some minor things.

```
 doc.childNodes
```

Then to get the tag of the element once you find the matching ID.

```
var x = document.getElementById("myP").tagName;
```

Comment: I need to print the tag Name ( Interaction), If I hard code the attribute value(Example: String attr="244_choice_list_12" ) it should return the **TAG NAME**. I don't know how to get a tag name?

Comment: No vote? My sources are w3cschools.com and "Internet programming World Wide Web" by Deitel. TT's explanation is cool but...you only need to know XML when working on antiquated projects.  XPath is such a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

This is best done with a proper XPath expression. Manual traversal of the XML is not the way. You wouldn't look up values in a database table by traversing a cursor on all rows, would you? No, you would write a SQL query to find the row(s) you need.

The same is true for XML. You would write the proper XPath expression, or XQuery. The XPath expression for what you want would be the simple `//*[@id='244_choice_list_12']`.

Look up a good tutorial on XPath. [This one from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) is a good one. Then look into how to use this in Java.

---

Example for your XML and query:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XPathTags {
    private static String xml=
"<itemBody class='etsmcm01fmt' id='244_item_content_3'>"+
"<rubric class='item_response_information ' id='244_item_response_information_21' use='instruction' view='author proctor scorer testConstructor tutor'/>"+
"<xi:include xmlns:xi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude' href='../Passage/205.qti.xml'/>"+
"<div class='stimulus_reference ' id='244_stimulus_reference_4'>"+
"    <p class='introduction passage-intro ' id='244_introduction_5'>Read<span class='formatted_text text_decoration:underline ' id='200244_formatted_text_6'>two</span> sentences</p>"+
"</div>"+
"<Interaction class='choice_list ' id='244_choice_list_12' maxChoices='4' minChoices='0' responseIdentifier='RESPONSE' shuffle='false'>"+
"    <prompt id='244_item_stem_8'>"+
"        <p class='stem_paragraph ' id='244_stem_paragraph_9'>story</p>"+
"    </prompt>"+
"    <simpleChoice class='block_choice ' id='200244_block_choice_13' identifier='i1'>"+
"        <p class='choice_paragraph ' id='200244_choice_paragraph_14'>North and south</p>"+
"    </simpleChoice>"+
"    <simpleChoice class='block_choice ' id='200244_block_choice_15' identifier='i2'>"+
"        <p class='choice_paragraph ' id='200244_choice_paragraph_16'>Sun and Moon</p>"+
"    </simpleChoice>"+
"    <simpleChoice class='block_choice ' id='200244_block_choice_17' identifier='i3'>"+
"        <p class='choice_paragraph ' id='200244_choice_paragraph_18'>uncomfortable.</p>"+
"    </simpleChoice>"+
"    <simpleChoice class='block_choice ' id='200244_block_choice_19' identifier='i4'>"+
"        <p class='choice_paragraph ' id='200244_choice_paragraph_20'>head.</p>"+
"    </simpleChoice>"+
"</Interaction></itemBody>";

    private static String xpathExpr=
"//*[@id='244_choice_list_12']";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpr);
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)),XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for( int i = 0; i != nodeList.getLength(); ++i ) {
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName());
            }
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Results in: `Interaction`

Comment: You are manually giving the XML, If i use Xml file from the local drives. what will be your solution?

Comment: @SrinivasanSeenu That's for you to find out. The example is to highlight my statement that you should be using XPath expressions to look up elements, attributes, ... in XML. There are plenty of tutorials online, plenty of examples on StackOverflow. Flex that Google-Fu!